# Chrome terminal offset so can't see what I'm typing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have this issue where I have only half a text showing when I'm typing.

[image]
How to fix?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Chrome? There once was a bug like this, but should be fixed.

Comment: yes v85........

Comment: Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official build) (64-bits)?